# Error adding items to the Grid

Tags: c#

**hello

Error adding items to the Grid.

please guide me**

```
Model1Container Mobl = new Model1Container();
JadvalSabtenam Sabt = new JadvalSabtenam();
Sabt.name = TextBox1.Text;
Sabt.family = TextBox2.Text;
Mobl.AddToJadvalSabtenamSet(Sabt);
Mobl.SaveChanges();

GridView1.DataSource = Sabt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is your error? You might also want to read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and  [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GridView1.DataSource = Sabt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

`Sabt` seems to be single object. To bind DataGrid you need to have collection like `List<JadvalSabtenam >` or `BindingList<JadvalSabtenam>`

Try that:

```
List<JadvalSabtenam > dataSource = new List<JadvalSabtenam> {Sabt};
GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Reason for that is: What Grid should do with single object? When it's collection each item is corresponding to one row, and each property to column which makes perfect sense.

Comment: tnx, error DataBind(); message error: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: try not doing DataBind method. Should work anyway. Or use BindingList<JadvalSabtenam> instead. Or add some more of your code, as maybe there is more things set that you never posted..

Answer (score 0):

thank you. very well.
My problem was solved with your code.

```
    List<JadvalSabtenam> dataSource = new List<JadvalSabtenam> { Sabt };
    GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
    GridView1.DataBind();
```